# coding XOR engine of two binary files in Python up to the length of the shorter one

Tags: python

I am on android and I am coding a source code of a program that is an implementation of the OTP cipher.

Could you please help me either by trying if my code works or by recommending a way I can try it online? I use online web compilers and they do not support working with files.

Thank you.

My code:

```
import os

n1="file.ttt"
n2="key.ttt"


f1=open(n1,"rb")
f2=open(n2,"rb")
f3=open("output1.ttt","wb")
 
file1_size=os.path.getsize(n1)
file2_size=os.path.getsize(n2)
min_size=min(file1_size,file2_size)


for x in range(0,min_size):
    s=f1.read(1)
    t=f2.read(1)
    s=str(bin(s[0]))
    s=s.replace("0b","")
    s=s.zfill(8)
    t=str(bin(t[0]))
    t=t.replace("0b","")
    t=t.zfill(8)
    
    s=list(s.split(""))
    t=list(t.split(""))
    
    l7=[]
    for i in range(8):
            l7.append(s[i] | t[i])
            
    d=""
    for i in range(8):
            d+=l7[i]
    d="0b"+d
    t=bytearray(d)
    f3.write(t)

f1.close()
f2.close()
f3.close()

f2=open(n2,"rb")
f4=open("output2.ttt","wb")
for x in range(0,min_size):
    t=f2.read(1)
    t=bytearray(t)
    f4.write(t)
f2.close()
f4.close()

print("Files output1.ttt and output2.ttt successfully created.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heart of modern* OTP encryption in Python is:

```
rv = bytes([i ^ j for i, j in zip(data, key)])
```

Where both `data` and `key` are `bytes`.
The `zip` iterator automatically stops when the shortest input is exhausted.

For generating keys, use `secrets.token_bytes()`, not the `random` module!

(* Modern as in using XOR of bytes instead of modulo addition of numbers representing letters.)

---

For trying Python online just search for "online python".